# Magento 2: What's the `ui_component` folder for?

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, view

In addition to containing familiar folders like `layout`, and `templates`, a Magento 2 module's `view` folder also contains a `ui_component` sub-folder.

```
view/adminhtml/ui_component
```

What is this folder for?  It seems to have something to do with rendering UIs in the back end, but it's not clear how I, as a Magento module developer, would use the files in this folder. Is this something reserved for core Magento modules that has no functionality exposed for third party developers, or can I use it to re-use Magento UI components and/or create my own UI components?  If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ui_component directory contains the xml definition of the grid (or form) used in the backend. Within you layout file you can reference to the ui component with:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="styles"/>
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <uiComponent name="sample_demolist_listing"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

This will then load the file: view/adminhtml/ui_component/sample_demolist_listing.xml, here you define (for a grid) what datasource you want to use, what fields available to show, fields that you want to filter on and mass-actions. See https://github.com/Genmato/M2_Sample/blob/7c0c771c4d66f2ea4eec285bfb9f8ad5d1c67999/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sample_demolist_listing.xml (file is a bit to big to include here).

The datasource is that is referenced in the ui_component xml is created thru the di.xml by defining:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sample_demolist_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Genmato\Sample\Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

In this case the collection is used from `Model\ResourceModel\Demo\Grid\Collection`.

See https://github.com/Genmato/M2_Sample/releases/tag/0.7.6 for usage in your own module.

Answer (score 7):

This folder contains declaration of [UI Components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-library/ui-library-component.html) based UI (like grids and forms). Currently it is used mostly in **adminhtml** area because Admin Panel have many CRUD interfaces that have same structure.

All new interfaces in Admin Panel will be build with UI components and also it's recommended technology for module development.

Comment: Maybe [sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent) will be useful for  you

Comment: Each node in here gets explained by this tutorial: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/